# How to add an image to a button?

Tags: javafx-2

I have followed the FX 2 tutorial in order to add a .png image to a button, but I didn't succeed.

The pointer.png is in package icons: in controller class I have try this

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    Image pointer = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("C:\\Users\\utente\\Desktop\\Java\\NewProjectX\\src\\icons\\Pointer.png"));
    togglebuttonPointer.setGraphic(new ImageView(pointer));
```

but it doesn't work.

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: what is the error? if the image couldn't be found, then look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Image pointer = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/icons/Pointer.png"));
```